# Rating with Rails (many_to_many)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to build a rating system into my app and currently stuck on the associations and indices. I'm quite new to this so I need all the help I can get...

**User model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :demos
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :reviewed, through: :ratings, source: :reviewed'Demo'
```

That's part of it.

**Demo model**

```
class Demo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :subject
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :reviewers, through: :ratings, source: :reviewer
```

The subject is irrelevant.

**Rating model**

```
class Rating < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :reviewed
  belongs_to :reviewer
  validates :rating, presence: true, numericality: { :greater_than_or_equal_to => 0, :less_than_or_equal_to => 5}
```

end
    end

And now you can tell I'm not really sure what I'm doing.

**Ratings Migration Table**

```
class CreateRatings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :ratings do |t|
      t.float :rating, default: 2.5     
      t.belongs_to :reviewed, index: true
      t.belongs_to :reviewer, index: true
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

**Demos Migration Table**

```
class CreateDemos < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :demos do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :subject, index: true
      t.string :name
      t.text :content
      t.string :materials
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :demos, [:user_id, :subject_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

I haven't built a controller for ratings yet since I'm just testing the relationships using the sandbox console.

I've successfully created a Rating, but @user.reviewed and @user.ratings returns a blank array in the Active Record even though @rating has all the Demo and User ids.

Comment: Aye, you set user/demo, but you don't set reviewer/reviewed. These two pairs of fields duplicate each other. You need only one of them, I think.

Comment: Good point...but I have a relationship with users and demos, where user has many demos. How would I use the THROUGH association for ratings with that in mind?

Comment: Huh? user-demo relationship doesn't have anything to do with ratings. Just remove user_id and demo_id from ratings.

Comment: Also, what's this got to do with polymorphism? Remove all of that, including the `_type` columns.

Comment: @TomLord: maybe he copied a wrong tutorial, or maybe he has several reviewable things.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I removed the polymorphic because I'm only reviewing one thing. When I try to do rating.reviewed = demo, it now gives me an error saying 'NameError: uninitialized constant Rating::Reviewed'. What does this mean? The same thing happens with users